# Laravel Excel combining multiple value into one cell

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

I wanted to export my table rekan that had many to many relationship with penyakits, for example one rekan instance could have a lot of penyakits. I wanted all multiple values that I got from many-to-many relationship to be set in one cell only (depending on the row of the instances that has that value).

Rxample with table that i wanted to make in Excel:

| Rekan Name | Penyakits |
| --- | --- |
| Rekan 1 | Penyakits x, penyakits y, penyakits z. |
| Rekan 2 | Penyakits x, penyakits y. |

This is my code that currently I've been working on in Laravel excel using only `WithStyle` (because I found that this method is the most flexible way to custom my sheets).

```php
$rowData = 4;
        foreach($rekans as $rekan){
            $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$rowData,$rekan->rekan_inv);
            $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$rowData,$rekan->dokter->nama_dokter);
            $sheet->setCellValue('C'.$rowData,$rekan->pasien->nama);
            $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$rowData,$rekan->pasien->klien->nama);
            $sheet->setCellValue('E'.$rowData,$rekan->berat);
            $sheet->setCellValue('F'.$rowData,$rekan->suhu);
            $sheet->setCellValue('G'.$rowData,$rekan->anamnesa);
            $sheet->setCellValue('H'.$rowData,$rekan->hasil_pemeriksaan);
            $sheet->setCellValue('J'.$rowData,$rekan->treatment->nama_treatment);
            $sheet->setCellValue('K'.$rowData,$rekan->pengobatan);
            $sheet->setCellValue('L'.$rowData,$rekan->kasus);
            $sheet->setCellValue('M'.$rowData,Date::dateTimeToExcel($rekan->created_at));

            foreach($rekan->penyakit as $penyakit){
                $sheet->setCellValue('I'.$rowData,$penyakit->nama_penyakit);
            }
```

Comment: Obviously this is just going to set the value over and over again. Why not just put them together in a string and then set the value to that?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) for how to make tables properly in your question BTW.

Comment: hi, mike thanks for your comment, could you show me how to put them together in a string? i'm confused on how to set the coma and dot properly.

Comment: thank you karel for correcting my question and helping me with those tables @karel, i'm sorry for my bad grammar before and about the tables too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on mikens idea, i manage to found the solution by using this code. thanks miken

```
$listpenyakit = [];
            $fixpenyakit = "";
            foreach($rekan->penyakit as $penyakit){
                array_push($listpenyakit,$penyakit->nama_penyakit);
            }
            if (count($listpenyakit) > 1) {
                $fixpenyakit = implode(", ",$listpenyakit);
            } else {
                $fixpenyakit = implode($listpenyakit);
            }
            $fixpenyakit .= ".";
            // dd($fixpenyakit);
            $sheet->setCellValue('i'.$rowData,$fixpenyakit);
```