# How to handle multiple submit request at a time in laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I have a Laravel website which is hosted in EC2 instance already, but the problem is, I have page for uploading the data by taking Excel files as input. If 2 users logged in to the website and they are trying to load the data from their end, if 2 user gave submit at a time we are getting some random errors in database. I have used SQL Server as my database.

Can somebody tell me how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Random errors in database? Can you be more specific? Also can you share the code you are using to handle the uploads?

Comment: maybe it can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72278031/laravel-excel-combining-multiple-value-into-one-cell

Comment: if you need to do the task one by one use laravel queue job

Comment: By using laravel queue how i can implement this, like I have same upload page for all the users but every user is having different logins, they will load the data of their by using this upload page, so the problem is if 2 or more users try to upload the data and that data is going to insert to same table at that time my database is giving some errors if i do it by 3/4 seconds variations its getting update but if do it at a using 2 users it not getting update

Comment: at a time if 2 upload requests are hit that time we r getting errors thats all, so we need to handle that upload requests